# how is it possible to modify the given output in python

Tags: python

I have been working on a code for practicing purpose in python which is:

```
     if information is not None:


                        option = information.attrib.get("option_select")
                        increment(operatormap,presenter)

                        if "OPT" in option:

                            z = option.split('.')
                            if z:
                                print(z[-1])
```

which gives an output like this:

```
2
1
1
3
4
4
```

im trying to modify and divide the output into two types which is something like:

```
not 1
1
1
not 1
not 1
not 1
```

how is it possible? can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I've misunderstood your question but would it not be possible to just add another if-clause?

Something like:

```
if z[-1] == 1:
    print(z[-1])
else:
    print('Not 1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("1" if z[-1] == 1 else "not 1")
```

Comment: even this prints all "not 1"

Comment: have you thougt about a mistake in your code after you got three answers that all print it wrong? Maybe you are using strings in your array... try 

`print("1" if z[-1] == "1" else "not 1")`

Comment: im sorry..i know that im doing something wrong here. im still learning

Comment: no problem, have you tried what i suggested in the comment above?

Comment: then in your arrays you do not have integer numbers like this: `[1,2,3,4]` but strings. So your array looks like: `["1", "2", "3", "4"]`.

Comment: I got it. thanks. ill keep this in mind. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if z[-1] != 1:
     print("not 1")
else:
     print("1")
```

Comment: tried this, only "not 1" prints..it doesn't print "1"

Comment: could you add this statement type(z) after z = option.split('.')  and see the datatype of z